# 'Not allowed to load local resource' security on WebKit?

Tags: network, safari, security, google-chrome, monterey

I just bought a 2021 software version of this famous tax program, but I'm unable to use it because the "submit" buttons do not work.

Upon close inspection (inspect element), I see the problem is likely CORS... however since this is a packaged app I assume it uses some kind of WebKit WebView... which I have no idea how to "allow" system-wide.

I know one can simply disable these security constraints on Safari, or Chrome but I see no way to do it system-wide so that this app works.

I called support for the software but they are perplexed... I was able to run this on a different machine, with the same OS version (12.2.1) so maybe there's luck?

[image: Error shown when doing inspect element]

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the problem is CORS? - Your screenshot does not contain information that would allow you to conclude that. I assume this app is based on Electron or similar framework with an embedded browser - and that is not the same as just opening the HTML files in Safari directly from the app bundle.

Comment: Well maybe it's not CORS, but some other security feature I don't know how to call :( anyhow, I'm surprised it works on a different machine, with same OS version. Ideas?

Comment: Ah, but why do you think it is a security feature at all? - You're opening these pages in a browser and then yes, you get CORS failures - but that's expected. The pages are not intended to be loaded from a file:// URL in a browser - that will always give you origin problems in modern browsers. The pages are supposed to be loaded through the built-in server within the Electron app into its built-in web browser. That way you do not have origin problems. Therefore I'm suggesting that you have a completely different type of problem here; you're diagnosing it incorrectly and getting the wrong cause

Comment: Have you tried connecting the web debugger directly to the webview in the Electron app instead? - That should give you the actual cause of the problem. Also submit a bug report to the developer.

Comment: Oh, the screenshot is of the electron app, I just did right click, inspect and the errors seem to be based on not being able to load files (and thus JS doesn't work). I will try the web debugger route tomorrow if I can figure out how to. I did send them feedback, but trying to work around it as this is a tax software and the deadline is approaching hahaha.

Comment: Ah - if that’s the case, then it looks like that software isn’t made with best practices at all. You cannot disable CORS or origin checking in general, nor is it usually possible to do in the actual browser engine (except by recompiling the browser - but that’s probably a bit out of scope here).

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand your situation, you have an app based on Electron or similar framework with an embedded browser. There's no generic setting in macOS that will allow you to disable CORS checks in all such embedded browsers.

Comment: Why the down vote? - Please leave an explanation of why you're downvoting, otherwise it is really hard to improve the answer.